# laravel.log under storage/logs gives Permission denied error after upgrade to 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

After upgrading to 5.5 from Laravel 5.4 I get a horrible error as you can see below.

```
(1/1) UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/home/vagrant/Code/website/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied**
```

1. Tried to change the permissions with chmod
2. Also tried to change my vagrant sync folders to the Homestead environment I work with.
3. Also everything is updated to the last version.

Comment: sudo chmod 777 storage/logs/laravel.log

Answer (score 1):

You need to change owner permission and chmod also. Use below command in terminal:

```
sudo chown -Rf www-data:www-data /home/vagrant/Code/website/storage/
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you report means that the server cannot write to

```
/home/vagrant/Code/website/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

This can happen for several reasons and you probably have not checked all of them:

1. The *file* cannot be written
2. The *folder* cannot be written
3. Any of the path components below cannot be accessed (this is a common gotcha)

So, the **web server user** must be able to do **all three of the above**. You must then:

- determine the web server's user and group (daemon, nobody, www-data, etc.)
- verify that all the path components (folder included) have the proper permission for that user.
- the folder (here, "logs") must have write permission.

The usual suggestion of "set all to 777 (or 'rwxrwxrwx')", *while undoubtedly working*, is unsecure because it grants everybody every right.

One way of verifying that everything is copacetic is to impersonate the appropriate user (if permissible) and try following the path. Here, as root:

```
# su nobody -c "ls /var"
(output omitted)
# su nobody -c "ls /var/www"
(output omitted)
# su nobody -c "ls /var/www/test"
ls: cannot open directory '/var/www/test': Permission denied
```

In the above example, being able to read and write in *logs* may not be enough, because a parent directory cannot be entered.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Change the following paramaters:

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

To:

```
user = vagrant
group = vagrant
```

Remember to restart PHP FPM

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod -R o+w /home/vagrant/Code/website/storage
```

have you tried giving this permission ?

Answer (score -1):

## setenforce 0

if selinux has been enabled on your system you have to disable it as the above command.
I hope it would help you.